Unsteady change in angle of attack
I am looking at this paper for unsteady propeller blade loading estimation in non-uniform flow.
According to the paper, we can estimate the thrust of a propeller blade section in non-uniform flow by multiplying the quasi-steady thrust with the Sears function S:
$T'_{us}(r,\sigma) = T'_{qs}(r,\sigma) S(r,\sigma)$
r = radial section; sigma = reduced frequency.
The quasi-steady thrust is just the outcome of a change in the sectional advance ratio due to non-uniform flow.
I am wondering if there's such a thing as "unsteady change in angle of attack" too, or that is only quasi-steady, thus entirely dependent on the change in local advance ratio.

There is such a thing as an unsteady angle of attack if you define the term -- what do you mean by that?  In the context of your question I could see how it might be meaningful if you were making rapid changes in propeller pitch -- is that what you mean?
